# Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error using OPENROWSET as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SELECT * FROM 
dbname1..tablename') AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'Server=localhost\sql2022;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SELECT TOP 5 
* FROM dbname2..tablename') AS a
```

The code is just for testing. It works fine in SSMS, but backend that runs this code fails with:

```
Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists
```

Not sure exactly what to do. Just to note. I can make it work with linked servers, but I need that code to work.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the backend is using a different account than your local system, so the auth token passed on to the target servers via trusted_connection is different.

Comment: Should I instead of Trusted Connection provide SQL user name and password?

Comment: Or have the "backend" run as a service account that all involved instances of SQL Server trust.

Comment: Not sure, service account can be changed. I prefer to modify anything within SQL code only.

Comment: Aside... it's in your best interests to find a different driver than `SQLNCLI` (aka. `SNAC` aka. SQL Native Client), as Microsoft has **finally** [removed it from SQL Server 2022 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client).

Comment: Right, it is useful info, but what I am working on is just a recommendation for the clients how to deal with multi server scenario when they create their custom reports. This code works in SSMS, but  fails in the backend. At this point all I am trying to make it work in principal.